# Why is pressing back removing all the navigation bar information whilst in landscape?

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationbar, uiinterfaceorientation

I've not been able to find anyone speaking of the same problem but i'm quite happy to be pointed to a post where something like this has been resolved.

As it stands, in portrait.

Picture 1: shows a media list, you can click a piece of media

Picture 2: you press the back arrow "<"

Picture 3: It returns you back to the correct page with everything working

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now, when I attempt to do this with a landscape orientation (locked or unlocked). 
As you can see, "View Media" at the top has disappeared and so has the Logout button.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Some things i've noticed about the problem:**

 After carrying out that second sequence in landscape mode, if I rotate to portrait all the features return. I've also noticed that while it's animating from the View Media page to the piece of media, if I click back ("< View Media") while the black bar is coming across (picture below) it all is there when I go back.

[image]

I've got nothing in the code that affects the orientation anymore as I thought i'd remove it all to start debugging but i've tried quite a few things and I think i'm barking up the wrong tree. Anyone pointing me in the right direction would be helpful! Thank you

Comment: question... where are you setting the "View Media" title and the Logout button? In the XIB/Storyboard or in code? If code, where in the code?

Comment: I've played a lot with different things but 
    [[self tabBarController] setTitle:@"View Media"]; is in the viewDidAppear. The logout button is actually set on the tab bar controller and i've dragged it to a class called TabBarController in which it's connected to - (IBAction)logoutButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self promptLogoutQuestion];
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, let me know if you need anything else. I've got a fake 'fix' at the moment, i've just created a fake back button that just pops the current navigation controller and it works in all orientations.

Comment: If you breakpoint on the viewDidAppear method where the title is set, is it called when you navigate back in Landscape?

Comment: Yeah, it is set. It is really weird but i've found out what is causing it. If I turn on the status bar (if you notice, it's disabled in the landscape view media bit) it starts fully working.. I don't understand why to be honest though and it's annoying because I want no status bar as there's no point in it being there.

Comment: That *is* weird... I'd think there must be way for them to function normally without the status bar.

Comment: Yep, it seems to be using a fake back button as it stands...

Comment: worth filing a Radar for? Or check out the dev forums?

Comment: i'll submit it if i get a chance but i'm really busy sadly :( work-around it is for the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem but I wouldn't really call it an answer. I've got the status bar hidden on the second VC in landscape but when I show it everything resumes fully working.. If I want to hide the status bar i'm having to create a fake back button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popVC)];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

then in popVC just

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```